# В каком падеже писать?

Tags: лексика

В каком падеже писать перечень в следующей фразе: "Информация предоставляется по следующим вопросам:
1. Перечень ...   или По перечню..."?

Comment: В вопросе мало данных для однозначного ответа. Необходимо привести перечень.

Answer (score 0):

В именительном. 1. Перечень...

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, в дательном падеже.

Answer (score 0):

Трудно сказать, не имея контекста. Пример бы надо. Вообще трудно представить, чтобы некий "перечень" был неким вопросом, даже под номером 1.